# Make a React Material-UI component to stick to the bottom-right of the screen

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am making a CRUD application and I want to display the **'Create'** control as a `Fab` button that sticks to the botton-right side of the screen, and to stay there in despite of screen scrolling.

I could, finally, make the button to remain still when the screen is scrolled, but I can't find how to set its position to the bottom-right of the screen.

This is the code of my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import axios from 'axios';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';
import Album from './Album.js'

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    overflowX: 'auto',
  },
  table: {
    minWidth: 700,
  },
  fab: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
  extendedIcon: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
});

class AddAlbumFloatingButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const {classes} = props;
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Fab color="primary" aria-label="Add" className={this.props.classes.fab} style={{position: 'fixed'}}>
          <AddIcon />
        </Fab>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

AddAlbumFloatingButton.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

class Albums extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    ...
  }

  getData() {
      ...
  }

  callDetail(instance) {
    ...
  }

  callList() {
    ...
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.mode === 'table'){
      return (
        <div>
          <AddAlbumFloatingButton classes={this.state.classes}/>
          <AlbumsTable classes={this.state.classes} albums={this.albums} onCallDetail={this.callDetail}/>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (<AlbumDetail instance={this.state.instance} onCallList={this.callList} />);
    }

  }
}

Albums.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Albums);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add required styling to your class `fab`:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  ...
  fab: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit, // You might not need this now
    position: "fixed",
    bottom: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    right: theme.spacing.unit * 3
  },
  ...
});
```

And remove `style` prop from your `<Fab>` component as it is already mentioned in the class. As with normal HTML and CSS, it is best to keep all styling in classes to make them reusable and have better [separation of concerns](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/32614/254549).

The styling applied above is again only some CSS: it fixes the element at the bottom, with spacing at the bottom and right according to your theme setting.

Update: `theme.spacing.unit` will be deprecated in Material UI v5. Check (and upvote) [@yogescicak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61056750/5838198) for the updated version!

Answer (score 10):

This is in reference to @Siavas's answer above in specifying `spacing` that has been deprecated and will be removed in MUI v5.
[image]

You may do the following instead:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  ...
  fab: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit, // You might not need this now
    position: "fixed",
    bottom: theme.spacing(2),
    right: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  ...
});
```