# How should a set width nav be made into a sticky in Material UI?

Tags: material-ui, material-design

New to Material UI I'm trying to create a sticky `div` with a set width similar to how Material UI has their side `nav` on the right of their docs. For some reason I'm unable to get the `div` to stick. Per research and the docs I've read through several questions and here are my attempts:

### Attempt 1

I tried utilizing `Box` but it scrolls with the page:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Hidden, Box, List,ListItem } from '@material-ui/core/'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  box: {
    background: 'red',
    position: 'sticky',
    top: 70,
    bottom: 20,
    paddingTop: 100,
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    width: 300,
  },
  sub: {
    display: 'block',
    overflow: 'auto',
  },
}))

const SideToc = ({ nav }) => {
  const { box, sub } = useStyles()
  return (
    <>
      <Hidden smDown>
        <Box className={box}>
          Contents
          <List className={sub} component="nav" aria-label="main mailbox folders">
            <ListItem button>Monday</ListItem>
            <ListItem button>Tuesday</ListItem>
            <ListItem button>Wednesday</ListItem>
          </List>
        </Box>
      </Hidden>
    </>
  )
}

export default SideToc
```

### Attempt 2

after research I've found a few mentions of `Drawer` but when I deploy the below component my green `drawerPaper` is fixed to the left and my blue `Drawer` is to the right a correct width.

```js
import React from 'react'
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer'
import Hidden from '@material-ui/core/Hidden'
import List from '@material-ui/core/List'
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const SideToc = ({ nav }) => {
  const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar, // necessary for content to be below app bar
    drawer: {
      background: 'blue',
      width: 300,
      flexShrink: 0,
    },
    drawerPaper: {
      marginTop: 120,
      background: 'green',
    },
  }))

  const { toolbar, drawer, drawerPaper } = useStyles()
  return (
    <>
      <div className={toolbar} />
      <Hidden smDown>
        <nav className={drawer} aria-label="mailbox folders">
          <Drawer
            classes={{
              paper: drawerPaper,
            }}
            variant="permanent"
          >
            Contents
            <List component="nav" aria-label="main mailbox folders">
              <ListItem button>Monday</ListItem>
              <ListItem button>Tuesday</ListItem>
              <ListItem button>Wednesday</ListItem>
            </List>
          </Drawer>
        </nav>
      </Hidden>
    </>
  )
}

export default SideToc
```

Here is my parent component that has the content with the set width `nav`:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

// Components
import SideToc from './SideToc'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar, // necessary for content to be below app bar
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    overflow: 'hidden',
    background: 'orange',
  },
}))

const Parent = ({ nav, children }) => {
  const { content, toolbar } = useStyles()

  return (
    <>
      <main className={content}>
        <div className={toolbar} />
        {children}
      </main>
      <SideToc className={toolbar} nav={nav} />
    </>
  )
}

export default Parent
```

### Research

- [How to make a Material UI grid element sticky?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65147684/how-to-make-a-material-ui-grid-element-sticky)
- [Reactjs Material-ui hide appBar sticky or static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65997384/reactjs-material-ui-hide-appbar-sticky-or-static)
- [Make a React Material-UI component to stick to the bottom-right of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54393446/make-a-react-material-ui-component-to-stick-to-the-bottom-right-of-the-screen)
- [React Material-Ui Sticky Table Header with Dynamic Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64164702/react-material-ui-sticky-table-header-with-dynamic-height)

In Material UI if I want a `div` to be sticky that will not scroll and have a fixed width how should that be done? Is my issue due to my parent? Should I be using Material's `Grid` in this approach?

---

### Edit

After further testing I am able to get the side `nav` to stick but the content, if outside the viewport, will not allow scrolling. The parent component has been modified with just a `div` surrounding the `SideToc` component:

```js
<>
<main className={content}>
  <div className={toolbar} />
  {children}
</main>

<div>
  <SideToc toc={toc} />
</div>
</>
```

SideToc Component:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Hidden, Box, List, ListItem } from '@material-ui/core/'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  box: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    top: theme.spacing(8),
    width: 250,
    position: 'sticky',
    right: 0,
    overflowY: 'auto',
    flexShrink: 0,
  },
}))

const SideToc = ({ nav }) => {
  const { box } = useStyles()

  return (
    <>
      <Hidden smDown>
        <Box className={box} component="nav">
        Contents
          <List component="nav">
            <ListItem button>Monday</ListItem>
            <ListItem button>Tuesday</ListItem>
            <ListItem button>Wednesday</ListItem>
          </List>
        </Box>
      </Hidden>
    </>
  )
}

export default SideToc
```

Per request:

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

Comment: If you make something like codesandbox.io example we will be able to help, because it sounds like you have rare issue with sticky, it is very easy so just make lil example to work with.

Comment: @Tiffany a stripped CodeSandBox has been added to the question.

Comment: You mean like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-heisenberg-2e1i6

Comment: no sorry. Where the right side of "contents" should be a sticky but still allow scrolling. Similar to how to docs are doing it.

Comment: Ok now I understood it was not clear what you wanted. Wait please...

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-heisenberg-2e1i6 try this

Comment: So the issue is with the contents of `Box`? Also in the sandbox when click the links for sections the header is under `Appbar`. So the solution to the issue is to use `Scrollspy`?

Comment: You just should add little paddings and margins here and there to fix issues. Yes why not use  Scrollspy it is valid package and works perfectly.